# A diffeomorphism with negative Jacobian swaps the orientation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Let C be a simple close oriented curve $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a diffeomorphism such that $\forall (x, y) \in C$ it holds that the determinant of the Jacobian of $g$ evaluated at $(x, y)$ is negative. Do $g(C)$ and $C$ have different orientations?

In other words, every diffeomorphism that inverts the orientation of $C$ has a negative value in $C$ for the determinant of the Jacobian of $g$ and viceversa?

Comment: You have assumed that $C$ has been given along with a specific orientation. That is what it means for $C$ to be "oriented" (by the way the term "orientated" is incorrect). However, you have **not** assumed that any specific orientation has been given for $g(C)$ and so the question cannot be answered in this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not quite make sense as stated; see my comment.

But with a slight interpretation, one can make sense of it. Namely, let's assume that both $C$ and $g(C)$ are assigned the "induced orientation" whereby if $T$ is a tangent vector pointing in the direction of the orientation and if $N$ is a normal vector pointing towards the inside (which makes sense by application of the Jordan curve theorem) then the pair of vectors $(T,N)$ satisfies the right hand rule, i.e. the determinant of this pair is positive.

In that case the answer to your question is yes. It can be proved by application of Green's theorem.

**Edit:** Here's a very very brief intuitive sketch. To make this rigorous it would be best to use the formulation of Green's Theorem in the language of differential forms.

Integrate $dx \, dy$ over the inside of $C$, you get the area inside $C$ which is positive. By the change of variables formula, since $g$ takes the inside of $C$ to the inside of $g(C)$, this positive number equals the integral of $|J(g^{-1})| \, dx \, dy$ over the inside of $g(C)$. Since $g$ reverses orientation, the integral of $J(g^{-1})\, dx \, dy$ is negative.

Now apply Green's theorem: integrating the vector field $x \, dy$ counterclockwise around $C$, you get a positive number. Arguing by contradiction, **if** $g$ takes the counterclockwise orientation on $C$ to the counterclockwise orientation on $g(C)$ then, when you push the vector field $x \, dy$ forward using $g$ and integrate around $g(C)$ in the counterclockwise direction, and when you apply the change of variables formula for path integrals, you would get a positive number. However, applying Green's theorem again, this would be equal to the integral of $J(g^{-1}) \, dx \, dy$ which is a negative number. Contradiction.

Comment: Is the proof simple? I explain myself, I was trying to proof that if Green's Theorem holds in $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, it also holds in $g(A)$, being $g$ a diffeomorphism, and what I need to complete the proof is that the diffeomorphism with negative determinant of the Jacobian inverts the orientacion of the bound of $A$

Answer (score 1):

The curve $C$ and the region it bounds $D$ have orientations that are related to each other.

First, what is an orientation?  One definition is the choice of a tangent $n$-vector for the $n$-dimensional region $D$.  In this case, you can choose $I = e_1 \wedge e_2$ or $I = e_2 \wedge e_1$, which are additive inverses of each other.

What is the induced orientation on $C$?  I submit it is the choice of tangent vector $c$ on $C$ so that it, combined with the outward normal vector $n$, forms the relation

$$n \wedge c = I$$

for whatever choice of orientation $I$.  One can further restrict that $n$ and $c$ should be orthogonal.

Now, given a diffeomorphism $g$, the Jacobian $\underline g$ maps vectors (as opposed to positions) as follows:

$$v' = \underline g(v)$$

But more importantly, it can also be used to map the *orientation* I.  If $I = e_1 \wedge e_2$, then define

$$\underline g(I) = \underline g(e_1 \wedge e_2) \equiv \underline g(e_1) \wedge \underline g(e_2)$$

As there is only one linearly independent 2-vector built from vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, the result *must* be $\underline g(I) = \alpha I$ for some scalar $\alpha$--namely, $\alpha = \det \underline g$.  (This can also be taken as a definition of the determinant.)

Now then, if $\det \underline g < 0$, what happens?  We get the new orientation $I' = -I$.  What does that do to our definition of the induced orientation?  We get

$$n' \wedge c' = I' = -I = - n \wedge c$$

Now, it usually won't be the case that $n = n'$, but we're not interested in actually computing $c'$: rather, we just want to know what it is *relative* to the outward normal.  If, for instance, $c$ were counterclockwise from $n$ initially, is $c'$ still counterclockwise from $n'$?  No, clearly not, for rotational invariance of $I$ tells us that if the relative orientations of $c'$ and $n'$ were the same as $c$ and $n$, then $n' \wedge c'$ would be equal to $I$, not $-I$.  The same argument holds if $c$ were initially oppositely oriented.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive approach, maybe: If you consider $\tilde{g} = s \circ g$, where $s(x,y) =(-x,y)$ or in other words $g$ with an additional mirroring in the image, then $\tilde{g}$ is orientation preserving since $\det D\tilde{g} = \det D s \det Dg = -\det Dg$. So any map with negative jacobian is the mirror image of an orientation preserving map, so it will swap the orientation.

In fact this holds in much more complicated situations, for example on manifolds. If they are orientable, there will alway be exactly two orientations and the sign of the Jacobian always determines whether you keep the orientation or switch to the other one.

Comment: I think your argument doesn't proof anything but if exists a diffeomorphism with negative or positive determinant of the Jacobian which inverts the orientation then exists a diffeomorphism with the the opposite sign of the jacobian which preserves the orientation. But saying that, it could exist both, diffeomorfisms with positive or with negative Jacobian, that inverts the orentation. I mean, that doesn't prove that the diffeomorphisms with negative jacobian inverts the orientation. Am I wrong?

Comment: You of course have to prove that the map $s$ inverts the orientation, and that diffeomorphisms with positive jacobian preserve the orientation, which may depend a bit on how you define orientation but otherwise should be doable.

Comment: Well, the first one is easy, but I have no idea about how to prove the second one. I mean, that diffeomorphisms with positive jacobian preserve the orientation.

Comment: It usually is one of the lemmata that is proven directly after defining orientation and of course depends on the definition (sometimes orientation is even defined as "the thing thats preserved by diffeomorphisms with positive jacobian"). I assume you just have the $\mathbb{R}^2$ definition that the orientation is positive if the area enclosed by the curve is "left" of the curve. In this case, you can show this by noting that the inside area is mapped to the inside area and then look at how tangent and normal vector transform for single point near the boundary.